# Помогите исправить ошибку expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: python, файлы, tkinter, txt, filedialog

Прошу прощения за неудобства кто пытался помочь. Ошибку выдаёт на этом фрагменте кода:

```
def dataInsert():
    global tree
    global count
    global file
    data = [dateEntry.get(), serviceEntry.get(), monthEntry.get(), borrowEntry.get(), spentEntry.get()]
    if dateEntry.get() and serviceEntry.get() and monthEntry.get() and borrowEntry.get() and spentEntry.get():
        with open(file, "a+"):
                file.write(str(data) + "\n")
                tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=count, values=data)
                count+=1
                clearEntry()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "You should write something in the text boxes")
```

И собственно говоря какую ошибку выдаёт:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\5kara\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\pyProjects\bills\bills.py", line 90, in dataInsert
    with open(file, "a+"):
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not TextIOWrapper
```

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.ttk import *
import os
#initializing window
root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
root.title("Bills")
genIco = PhotoImage(file="money.png")
root.iconphoto(False, genIco)
# initializating file
file = None
# creating tree.
tree = Treeview(root)
#initializingcolumns
tree["columns"] = ("Date", "Service", "Month", "Borrow", "Spent")
#setting up columns
tree.column("#0", width=40, minwidth=40 , anchor=W, stretch=False)
tree.column("Date", width=120, minwidth=120, anchor=W, stretch=False)
tree.column("Service", width=160, minwidth=160, anchor=W, stretch=False)
tree.column("Month", width=120, minwidth=120, anchor=W, stretch=False)
tree.column("Borrow", width=90, minwidth=90, anchor=W, stretch=False)
tree.column("Spent", width=90, minwidth=90, anchor=W, stretch=False)
#setting up headings
tree.heading("#0", text="№", anchor=W)
tree.heading("Date", text="Date", anchor=W)
tree.heading("Service", text="Service", anchor=W)
tree.heading("Month", text="Month", anchor=W)
tree.heading("Borrow", text="Borrow", anchor=W)
tree.heading("Spent", text="Spent", anchor=W)
#count
global count
count=0
#creating entry's
dateEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
serviceEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
monthEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
borrowEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
spentEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
# ========================================================================================        
# ====================================MENU===============================================

# def createNew():
#

def openFile():
    global file
    file = root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/bills", title="Open a file", filetypes=(("Text Document", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")))  
    with open(file) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line
            tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=count, values=data)
# ========================================================================================        
# ====================================BUTTONS============================================
#clearEntry
def clearEntry():
    dateEntry.delete(0, END)
    serviceEntry.delete(0, END)
    monthEntry.delete(0, END)
    borrowEntry.delete(0, END)
    spentEntry.delete(0, END)
#fillEntry
def fillEntry():
    selected_item = tree.focus()
    details = tree.item(selected_item)
    date = details.get("values")[0]
    service = details.get("values")[1]
    month = details.get("values")[2]
    borrow = details.get("values")[3]
    spent = details.get("values")[4]
    dateEntry.insert(0, date)
    serviceEntry.insert(0, service)
    monthEntry.insert(0, month)
    borrowEntry.insert(0, borrow)
    spentEntry.insert(0, spent)
#autoFillEntry
# def autoFill():
#     if tree.selection:
#         fillEntry()
#insert
def dataInsert():
    global tree
    global count
    global file
    data = [dateEntry.get(), serviceEntry.get(), monthEntry.get(), borrowEntry.get(), spentEntry.get()]
    if dateEntry.get() and serviceEntry.get() and monthEntry.get() and borrowEntry.get() and spentEntry.get():
        with open(file, "a+"):
                file.write(str(data) + "\n")
                tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=count, values=data)
                count+=1
                clearEntry()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "You should write something in the text boxes")
    
#deleteAll
def dataDeleteAll():
    global tree
    global count
    global file
    for record in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(record)
        count-=count
    path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), file)
    os.remove(path)
    clearEntry()
#deleteLog
def dataDelete():
    global tree
    global count
    global file
    data = [dateEntry.get(), serviceEntry.get(), monthEntry.get(), borrowEntry.get(), spentEntry.get()]
    dele = tree.selection()[0]
    tree.delete(dele)
    with open(file):
        lines = file.readlines()
    with open(file, "w"):
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != str(data):
                file.write(line)
        count-=1
        clearEntry()

# ========================================================================================        
# ================================FINAL   SETTINGS==========================================
#creating label's
dateLabel = Label(root,
                  text="Date")
serviceLabel = Label(root,
                     text="Service")
monthLabel = Label(root,
                   text="Month")
borrowLabel = Label(root,
                    text="Borrow")
spentLabel = Label(root,
                   text="Spent")
#creating buttons
submitButton=Button(root, width=35, text="Submit", command = dataInsert)
deleteAllButton=Button(root, width=13, text="Delete All", command=dataDeleteAll)
deleteOneButton = Button(root, width=13, text="Delete One", command=dataDelete)
entryFill = Button(root, width=13, text="Fill Entry's", command=fillEntry)
#creating menu
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

fileMenu = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=fileMenu)
# add some commands in fileMenu
fileMenu.add_command(label="New")
fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save")
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Settings")
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit")
#placing widgets
dateEntry.place(x=100, y =260)
serviceEntry.place(x=100, y =290)
monthEntry.place(x=100, y =320)
borrowEntry.place(x=100, y =350)
spentEntry.place(x=100, y =380)

dateLabel.place(x=9, y=260)
serviceLabel.place(x=9, y=290)
monthLabel.place(x=9, y=320)
borrowLabel.place(x=9, y=350)
spentLabel.place(x=9, y=380)

submitButton.place(x=9, y=410)
deleteAllButton.place(x=230, y=259)
deleteOneButton.place(x=230, y=289)
entryFill.place(x=230, y=319)
tree.pack()
#run
# autoFill()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка - нужно угадать? Приведите полный стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Попробую угадать пока стека нет))Убедитесь, что переменной `file` присваивается корректное значение. Программа ожидает строку, а приходит "None". Для начала задайте ей пустую строку вместо None:

```
file = ""   # initializating file
```

Исходя из кода, ошибка должна появляться в `def openFile()`
можно добавить проверку :

```
def openFile():
    global file
    file = root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/bills", title="Open a file", filetypes=(("Text Document", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")))  
    if file:
        with open(file) as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                data = line
                tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=count, values=data)
```

Comment: Пробовал, не получилось. Добавил деталей в пост

Comment: смотрите, что передается в `file`. Вы пытаетесь открыть файл, используя объект, а должен быть путь к файлу. Что приходит в `file` посмотрите, через `Print(file)`.

Comment: команда выдала путь к файлу.

Comment: если `print(type(file))` у вас выдаст `<class 'str'>` тогда к сожалению я не понимаю, что за ошибка и откуда она берется . Вы же `Print(file)` берете сразу перед `with` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, получилось. Я чутка подумал и вот собственно говоря решение. Оно оказалось максимально простым. Мы должный создать вне функции переменную, значение должно быть = "". Я её назвал file_name. Так вот и теперь, мы присваиваем этой переменной переменную file которая у меня. И вуаля. Всё работает. Вот код:

````
    global file_name
    pathFile = root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/bills", title="Open a file", filetypes=(("Text Document", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*.*")))  
    file_name = pathFile
    print(pathFile)
    with open(pathFile) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line
            tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=count, values=data)```
````